# How to update NSG rule in C# with multiple ip addresses

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have C# code to update the ip address for an NSG rule:

```
var nsg = azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.GetByResourceGroup("rg", "testnsg");

var nsgrule = nsg.SecurityRules["testrule"];

nsg.Update().UpdateRule("testrule").ToAddress(IpAddress1);

nsg.Update().UpdateRule("testrule").ToAddress(IpAddress2);

nsg.Update().Apply();
```

The second ip address overwrites the first one.

I have also tried this:

```
nsg.Update().UpdateRule("testrule").ToAddress(IpAddress1 + ',' + IpAddress2);
```

But that gives an error that only one ip address is allowed.

Is there a way in C# to specify multiple ip addresses for the nsg rule?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        var nsg = azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.GetByResourceGroup("rg", "testnsg");
        var nsgrule = nsg.SecurityRules["testrule"];
        List<string> ips = new List<string>();
        ips.Add(IpAddress1);
        ips.Add(IpAddress2);
        nsgrule.Inner.DestinationAddressPrefixes = ips;
        nsg.Update().Apply();
```